# Run command on IntelliJ IDEA startup

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Is it possible to run a command on startup? The command would be:

```
git pull origin master
```

I already have both the repository / remote set and working.

---

**Background** (my specific problem)

I work in two different computers in different times of the day / week (Yeah, I know, I know, but it's not my choice, I can't change this).  I'd like to run that command everytime I open IntelliJ IDEA cause I'm forgetful and it's annoying to have to deal with git merging problems or things like that. Pulling on startup would help me big time.

**IDE Version:** IntelliJ IDEA Community 17.1.5
**OS:** Windows 7 x64

---

**Footnote**
Somehow, I generally don't forget to push the changes (only pull them), but it would be nice if there was a way to do it when IDE is closing too.

Comment: I just thought of it.. I suppose I could just create a batch that runs git and the IDE, but it would be nice to have a built-in functionality to do that. Anyways, if it's not really possible, I'll post the batch option as the answer, I guess.

Comment: write a bash file? instead of starting the IDE by its shortcut etc. run the bash file which will do the git command or what ever first than launch the ide

Comment: You can write a plug-in for that.

Comment: @UlugToprak Yeah, after I commented, I just tested a .bat file and it seems to work, but it looks so _wrong_ xD. I'll wait to see if anyone knows of a built-in solution and if not, I'll post an answer with the code I used.

Comment: @CrazyCoder hm.. I'm listening ^^. Any well-known reference?

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Oh, I thought you had something besides the docs in mind. Thanks anyways, I'll take a look.

Comment: Here's a wild untested thought: how about running your batch file as a [startup-task](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/startup-tasks.html)?

Comment: @Morfic It's not very clear, but I don't think it's related. That link seems to be about project startup (running it), not IDE startup.

Comment: Indeed, the documentation description is misleading, but if you go to that window in the IDE, you'll see as the header for the list of tasks: `To be started on project opening`. I figured this may be more powerful than running the bat when launching the IDE, because you can open and close the project multiple times without exiting Idea, and the tasks will be executed each time.

Comment: I guess they use 'project opening' meaning project running, cause they have the table column header as 'run configuration' and when I click the + button it shows the 'Run/Debug Configuration' window. As you said, quite misleading. Doesn't seems like it's what I'm looking for, but thanks anyways. @Morfic

Comment: Nope, those tasks will be executed when the project is opened. Its intended purpose is to be able to _prepare extra stuff_ required by your project, such as a local http server for your angular-js application. I suppose there is a limited list of tasks you can run based on what IJ supports and that's why they're reusing the `Run Dialog`. Also I assume you could run it as a `Bash` config and select `cmd` as the interpreter. I did a quick test with a JUnit, and it was run when the project was opened, so try it out. I'm very busy right now, but I'll try a complete scenario tomorrow if I can, sry